# Required package for 'starred version' of matrix environment

Tags: packages, matrices, starred-version

Whenever I am trying to compile the following code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{matrix*}[r]
-1 & 3 \\
2 & -4
\end{matrix*}  
 \end{document}
```

shows an error : `Environment matrix* undefined.`

I want to know what is the necessary package for

**'bmatrix*,Bmatrix*,vmatrix*,Vmatrix*,pmatrix*,matrix* '**

Comment: `mathtools` should do it.

Answer (score 19):

`mathtools` package, but I wonder how you could know those environments exist without seeing a document using that package?